# Can I use JavaScript to select 2 non-contiguous areas in an html document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, range

Suppose I have a DIV with many sentences.  I want to select the third word in each sentence (for example).  I have a collection of range objects that correspond to each word.  Is there a way to select each?

I could use the selectionRange addRange method, and add each range to it.  Hopefully this means that all the third words would be selected the same way as if I dragged my mouse across them with the left mouse button pressed down.  But I don't know if thats true.

Finally, the purpose of doing this is that, once I have the selection, I can color its background somehow.  I can't do that by an alternative method fo processing each range one by one surrounding each third word by span nodes with a colored background, because as soon as I do that, I throw off the parameters of the other stored ranges, whose computed offsets assume a DOM that was not tampered with.

Thanks.

Comment: If you already have the ranges, and you already believe that [`Selection.addRange()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/addRange) (see browser compatibility) will accomplish what you desire, why are you asking here instead of just trying it?

Comment: Good point Makyen.I just tried it.  It does not work.  So that leaves me the same question - how do I highlight different words in a HTML fragment given a set of ranges.  It would be easy, except that as soon as I do a highlight (by inserting nodes into the DOM that have a colored background), the ranges are no longer valid.

Comment: In which browser did you try it.  MDN does not specify the browser compatibility for [`Selection.addRange()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/addRange). So, I am curious.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. This will make it **much** easier for people to help you. It also helps keep people on the same page when discussing the issue, reducing confusion. Not having a [mcve] *significantly* reduces the number of people willing/able to help you. Even when someone does help, we have to *guess* at significant portions of what your problem might be which can result in answers which don't reflect what you desire.

Comment: I would suggest you do a search on how people do syntax highlighting or marking spelling/grammar errors. In general, this is usually done by creating a `<div>` that overlays/underlays the text content to which you desire to apply the formatting and changing the overlay/underlay format by adding the appropriate `<span>` elements. Adding the `<span>` elements directly into the single copy of the text has various potential issues.  The selection issue you are experiencing is one of them.

Comment: I'll do the search.  As far as selection.addRange(), I tried it on either Edge or Chrome, I forget which, but it has to work on both for my application.